# How to post Py get_rusults() into DataFrame() Knime output_table?

Tags: python, pandas, knime

I have code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from pandas import DataFrame
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.google.com" #just random web-site for demo
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    browser.get(url)
    searh_box = browser.find_element_by_id("q")
    searh_box.send_keys(search_term)
    searh_box.submit()
    browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    try:
        links = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('new-product-name')
    except:
        links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//a[@class='new-product-name']")
    results = []

    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute("href")
        print(href)
        results.append(href)

    browser.close()
    return results

get_results("0088381687300")

output_table = DataFrame()
```

I understand, that to put results from get_results into output_table some adjustments are needed: to take list of results and form a table with 1 column name.
But, I can not figure out how to do that.

Any help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to create a Pandas dataframe from your results list.

Assuming you call your new dataframe 'results' the last line of your code should look something like this:

output_table = results